# PHP, Smarty, how to get values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, templates, multidimensional-array, smarty, prestashop

I've got multidimensional array, like this:

```
Array (7)
    0 => Array (6)
      id => "31"
      link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
      name => "Gotowe"
      desc => ""
      id_parent => "28"
      children => Array (5)
            0 => Array (6)
                  id => "152"
                  link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
                  name => ""
                  desc => ""
                  id_parent => "31"
                  children => Array (0)
            1 => Array (6)
                  id => "153"
                  link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
                  name => ""
                  desc => ""
                  id_parent => "31"
                  children => Array (0)
            2 => Array (6)
                  id => "154"
                  link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
                  name => ""
                  desc => ""
                  id_parent => "31"
                  children => Array (0)
            3 => Array (6)
                  id => "155"
                  link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
                  name => ""
                  desc => ""
                  id_parent => "31"
                  children => Array (0)
            4 => Array (6)
                  id => "156"
                  link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
                  name => ""
                  desc => ""
                  id_parent => "31"
                  children => Array (0)

    1 => Array (6)
          id => "42"
          link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
          name => "Moda"
          desc => ""
          id_parent => "28"
          children => Array (6)
            0 => Array (6)
                id => "89"
                link => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."
                name => "SUKIENKI"
                desc => ""
                id_parent => "42"
                children => Array (0)
                {.....}
```

Then, in smarty, I've got:

```
{section name = "foo" loop = $node.children}
    {if $node.children[id_parent] == currentCategoryId}
        <li><p><span><a href = "{$node.children.children.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"  title="{$child.children.desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.children.children.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p></li>
    {/if}
{/section}
```

The point is, I need to get all links from an array where id_parent is equal to currentCategoryId. To be more precise, when I'm on the page of category with id = 42 (it's on the bottom of array code) I need to get all the links from it and put on the page.
I tried some `{foreach}`, but it didn't work, so now I'm trying `{section}`, and it also doesn't work properly. I stucked, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong access to loop elements and `$currentCategoriId` should have `$` at the beginning.

Loop should look like this:

```
{section name = "foo" loop = $node.children}
    {if $node.children[foo].id_parent == $currentCategoryId}
        <li><p><span><a href = "{$node.children[foo].link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"  title="{$node.children[foo].desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.children[foo].name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p></li>
    {/if}
{/section}
```

For PHP data like this:

```
$data =     Array (
'children' => array(
0 => array (
    'id' => "152",
         'link' => "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor...",
         'name' => "aaa",
          'desc' => "a desc",
          'id_parent' => "31",
),
1 => array (
    'id' => "22152",
    'link' => "22http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor...",
    'name' => "bbb",
    'desc' => "b desc",
    'id_parent' => "3122",
),

1 => array (
    'id' => "3322152",
    'link' => "3322http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor...",
    'name' => "ccc",
    'desc' => "c desc",
    'id_parent' => "31",
)

));

$smarty->assign('node',$data);

$smarty->assign('currentCategoryId',31);
```

I get desired output:

```
<li><p><span><a href = "http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."  title="a desc">aaa</a></span></p></li>
                <li><p><span><a href = "3322http://site.loc/index.php?id_categor..."  title="c desc">ccc</a></span></p></li>
```

Next time please provide data in PHP format as above in my answer. It's much easier to test it.

**EDIT**

Because you don't provide sample data in PHP format it's really hard to test it not knowing also what you assigned from PHP to Smarty, but I guess this should work for you:

```
{section name = "foo" loop = $node}
    {section name="bar" loop=$node[foo].children}
    {if $node[foo].children[bar].id_parent == $currentCategoryId}
        <li><p><span><a href = "{$node[foo].children[bar].link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"  title="{$node[foo].children[bar].desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node[foo].children[bar].name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p></li>
    {/if}
    {/section}
{/section}
```

Comment: That's array from @debug_print_var. I think your array looks a bit differ from mine, and it doesn't work for me. I've got assigned $children array and nothing else in my php file, I need to get to to last level of it, in this example to the children array which starts with name "SUKIENKI". I still think that it is possible to get values with properly using `section` but still, I don't now how.

Comment: If you don't provide your data in PHP format, I cannot help you more. Why cannot you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php to put correct data into question?

Comment: @stolarz I've added another possible solution to my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I try to provide data in PHP format but how to do this in smarty? I've got in blockcategories.php  

    $v = var_export($blockCategTree);
    $this->smarty->assign('v', $v);

and in blockcategories.tpl:  {$node.v}
Is it good approach?

Comment: @stolarz No, you should have show `var_export($blockCategTree);` result only in your question that users who want to help you have the same data as you have and how you assign those data to Smarty for example `$smarty->assign('node',$blockCategTree); `. Have you tested solution in my edited answer?

Comment: Ok, I made it, tomorrow I'll add answer, now I can't answer my own questions, thanks to you @Marcin Nabialek.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentCategoryId` might be treated as a string rather than a variable, add a dollar sign before it.

Comment: Right, there should be $ sign, but it still doesn't work. I have no links on my page, I think there might be mistake in `<a>` tag, but I can't solve it.